# android code to check if user is using app regularly

Tags: android

I want to show notification reminder to a user who has not been using my app for say last 7 days.

Is there any code for that? I google but found nothing. Was looking for some code which I can directly use.

I thought it should be very common requirement for developers.

Comment: Foe sure you can implement this by bind timer to your service but 100% client will remove your application (-1)

Comment: `I thought it should be very common requirement for developers.` - No,  I try not to annoy the user by forcing him to use my app. That's a very bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong but i think you should use the AlarmManager. So the alarm would trigger an activity that creates a new notification

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html